# versions of software with RHEL 5.4

Tags: rhel5

Is there any resource/web-page that lists the versions of the software that come with RHEL-AS 5.4?

In particular, I need the exact version of the Apache Web Server, Satellite, Data Services to list a few?

Edit: I dont have RHEL 5.4 AS installed, however, I need a source to find out the above.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look through here:

http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/

that is all the source RPMs that RHEL 5 (and all the updates) is built from - you can see the versions in the RPM filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -qa | grep httpd
```

will show you which version of the httpd (Apache) package you have installed.  Adjust the grep accordingly to get the other package versions.

Comment: @jamieb: updated the question. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any active, paid subscription for RHEL, you can access all the package data from channels within [RHN](https://www.redhat.com/wapps/sso/rhn/login.html?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Frhn.redhat.com%2Frhn%2FYourRhn.do).  If you don't have a paid subscription, you can check out something like [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat), which will have some of that information.